# Get list of all relationships from a table Flask SQLalchemy

Tags: python, flask, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a list of all the relationships for a table with Flask SQLAlchemy, but don't see any option, just on how to create relationships.
Does anyone know how I can do this? Any help is much appreciated.
Here is a simple example of 3 models. How can I get a list of the two relationships from the Member model?

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import Flask
import os
from flask_login import UserMixin

app = Flask(__name__)

file_path = os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()) + "\database.db"

app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///" + file_path
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "my secret!"

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Member(db.Model, UserMixin):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique = True)
    
    
    hobbies = db.relationship("Hobbies", backref="member", lazy="dynamic")
    
    friends = db.relationship("Friends", backref="member", lazy="dynamic")
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        
        self.name = name
        
    def __repr__(self):
        
        return "<Member {}>".format(self.id)
    

    
class Hobbies(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    hobby = db.Column(db.String(40))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    

    def __init__(self, hobby, user_id):
        
        self.hobby = hobby
        self.user_id = user_id
        
    def __repr__(self):
        
        return "<Hobbies {}>".format(self.id)
    
    
    
class Friends(db.Model):
    
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    friend = db.Column(db.String(40))
    
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
    

    def __init__(self, friend, user_id):
        
        self.friend = friend
        self.user_id = user_id
        
    def __repr__(self):
        
        return "<Friends {}>".format(self.id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from sqlalchemy.inspection import inspect

relations = inspect(Member).relationships.items()
```

Comment: You could loop over all the tables from `db.metadata.tables` and access all their relationships through the `inspect` method above.